# Convert a column with p values to fdr "BH method"

Tags: r, p-value

here is an example that looks like this and one of the column has p values that I want to convert to fdr by creating a new column. The method I want to use is BH (Benjamin Hochberg) correction.

```
a=c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
p_values=c(0.05,0.06,0.03,0.03,0.07,0.02)
df= data.frame(a, p_values)
df$FDR = paste(p_values)
df= p.adjust(df$FDR, method = "BH" )
```

The code results in removing rest of the column and only keeps new column with FDR.
Please assist
I am not sure that results are correct or not

Answer (score 1):

The last line should read:

```
df$FDR <- p.adjust(df$p_values, method = "BH" )
```

So you just change the one column and don't replace the data.frame with the resulting vector.

You also don't need to copy the p-values to the FDR column before doing this. The new column will be created, automatically, when you assign the values to it.

A full version of your example:

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
p_values <- c(0.05,0.06,0.03,0.03,0.07,0.02)
df <- data.frame(a, p_values)
df$FDR <- p.adjust(df$p_values, method = "BH")
```